# Ruby Net::HTTP POST send data gzip compressed

Tags: ruby, post, compression, gzip, net-http

I am using Net::HTTP::Post under JRUBY 1.9.2 to send data to a custom server (not a web server), that want the data to be gzipped compressed.

How can I tell Net::HTTP::Post to gzip compress the data it is POSTING?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Where have you searched? As is, you're asking us to write a tutorial for you and they exist already.

Comment: @theTinMan the ruby docs for Net::HTTP::POST mention nothing about compression.

Comment: You need to use `Zlib` to compress data and `Content-Encoding: gzip` header. None of this is specific to `Net::HTTP::POST`, AFAIK.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm experiencing a similar issue on jruby 9.0.5.x

Answer (score 4):

Example for posting JSON:

```
require('zlib')
require('net/http')
require('json')

data = {my: 'data'}
uri = URI('http://example.com/api/endpoint')

headers = {
  'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
  'Content-Encoding' => 'gzip',
}
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri, headers)

gzip = Zlib::GzipWriter.new(StringIO.new)
gzip << data.to_json
request.body = gzip.close.string

response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) do |http|
  http.request(request)
end
```